# Bootstrap Carousel Slide Show not working in FireFox

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap-5 Carousel Slide Show to run website banner. This Bootstrap-5 Carousel Slide Show is working fine in Google Chrome but not in Firefox, It is showing blank page (Blank Area of Banner slide). My Firefox browser version is - 90.0.2 (64-bit). But if i inspect the code, slide code is rotating, that shows that banner slide is moving, only visibility problem is there or we can say that Browser compatibility issue.

I am already using **bootstrap-5** css file of template - **bootstrap.min.css** and Bootstrap Bundle with Popper file - **bootstrap.bundle.min.js**

I have attached snap shot of both browser (Firefox and Chrome) to view it.

**Firefox SnapShot -**

[image]

**Google Chrome Snapshot**

[image]

```
        <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
      <!-- Required meta tags -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>Testing</title>

      <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
      
    </head>

    <body>
      <!-- ======= Headr Banner Section Starts======= -->
      <section>
        <div class="HomePageBannerr">
          <div id="carouselExampleFade" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-bs-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="img/banner/CSIR-NET-2020-Students-Results.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="img/banner/CSIR-UGC-NET-JRF-Dec-2019-Student-Results-Banner.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="img/banner/GATE-2021-Student-Results.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="img/banner/Gate-March-2020-Student-Results-Banner.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="img/banner/IIT-JAM-2021-Student-Results.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="img/banner/JAM--2020-Student-Results.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="img/banner/Student-Banner-CSIR-NET-Results-2019.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
              </div>
            </div>

            <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-bs-slide="prev">
              <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
            </button>
            <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-bs-slide="next">
              <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Please suggest how to resolve it.

Thanks

Comment: check answer and try this once!

Comment: Glad this work for you!

Comment: With captions - code is working, can you provide solution with - Crossfade?

Comment: because with "Crossfade" (part of code) the problem is same, I think in this part of code "carousel-fade" css creating some problem

Comment: I updated my code again check it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this for Crossfade**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <div id="carouselExampleFade" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="https://thumbs-prod.si-cdn.com/P4Smi9MthEBXH7pdW8Y-bvwR6ts=/1072x720/filters:no_upscale()/https://public-media.si-cdn.com/filer/04/8e/048ed839-a581-48af-a0ae-fac6fec00948/gettyimages-168346757_web.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://tr-images.condecdn.net/image/LDM0pgM40l1/crop/2040/f/gettyimages-1146431497.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://thumbs-prod.si-cdn.com/P4Smi9MthEBXH7pdW8Y-bvwR6ts=/1072x720/filters:no_upscale()/https://public-media.si-cdn.com/filer/04/8e/048ed839-a581-48af-a0ae-fac6fec00948/gettyimages-168346757_web.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-bs-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-bs-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
      </div>










    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-eMNCOe7tC1doHpGoWe/6oMVemdAVTMs2xqW4mwXrXsW0L84Iytr2wi5v2QjrP/xp" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cn7l7gDp0eyniUwwAZgrzD06kc/tftFf19TOAs2zVinnD/C7E91j9yyk5//jjpt/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

**Don't forget to verify my answer if it work for you**

Comment: OK, can you put some code here so I can check it?

Comment: I updated my source code so, try this one.

Comment: With captions Part of code it is working, But i am using - Crossfade - part of code, with that problem is same.... can you please go through with "Crossfade" part of code?

Comment: I already update code for crossfade check it!

Comment: one thing i noticed that when i am changing local SRC path for image instead of live image link, it stopped working in firefox but working in Google chrome properly. Any suggestion for this?

Comment: can you provide the source code of your problem? not in comment section edit your question.

Comment: Please check now.